# Json dumps writes invalid json to file with extra commas and wrong representation of booleans

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have the following **python2.7** code:

```
# Reads a json file, and overwrites it with an updated version 
with open('config.json','r+') as f:
    current_file_content = json.load(f)
    f.seek(0)
    # Function that updates the values of the dictionary
    # it is to illustrate. you can update the dictionary with your own function
    current_file_content = update_dictionary(current_file_content,update_content)
    # writes back to the file
    f.write(json.dumps(current_file_content, indent=4))
    f.truncate()
```

This code is running continuously reading the `config.json` file and updating it.
Most of the time is writes valid json.
However, some times it generates a `json` file that is invalid like this:

```
{
    "attribute1": {
        ,
        "a": 0,
        "b": "example"
    },
    "attribute2": {
        ,
        "c": True,
        "c": "example2"
    }
}
```

Notice the **extra commas** and that the **`True`** is represented as uppercase. That is not valid json. In fact, the extra commas make the file not even be a valid python dictionary.

**Has anyone seen this problem before and would know the cause of the issue and how to always generate valid json?**

Comment: Is this happening concurrently, i.e. two processes writing to the file at the same time? Since you don't seem to be caring about locking the file, this can easily lead to corruption.

Comment: It might happen that the same code above can be called twice maybe entering some write conflicts. I would expect that a corruption of a conflict like that would generate other artifacts, however it is always about the commas and the invalid booleans. No other error is present